# Не работает корректно POST запрос в Angular

Tags: javascript, http, post, angular, postman

Когда отправляю данные в Postman в body , то получаю статус 200
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда пытаюсь отправить запрос на тот же URL на Angular CLI , то получаю статус 400  - MALFORMED_JSON

```
 const testData = {
    "address_1": "ddd",
    "contact_person_1": "ddd",
    "full_name": "dsad",
    "is_active": 2,
    "phone_no_1": "11111",
  }
return this.http.post(`${this.urlAdmin}branches/save`, testData).pipe(
  catchError((err) => {
      console.log('err' , err)
    return of(false);
  })
);
```

Вот параметры которые отправляются в браузере. `token` я отправляю в header , но даже добавив свойствов в `testData` все равно не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто нибудь помочь ?

Comment: Лог ошибок есть с консоли браузера?

Comment: @Assur да есть https://prnt.sc/ue1b4a , я вот думаю может проблема в том , что если в боди отправляешь и все нормально в postman, а если параметрами то ошибка
как это сделать в Ангуляре ?!

Comment: Почитайте здесь: https://metanit.com/web/angular2/6.5.php.
Для примера: для организации POST запросов для web-сервиса  через REST API использую связку Angular + js сервер Hapi. Тут не все так просто.

Comment: `this.urlAdmin` - там правильная ссылка?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, если неправильная он бы ответил типо метода такого нету или другую ошибку

Comment: Поскольку мы видим, что JSON хорошо распарсился в браузере, значит проблема на бакенде.